# casting a date field to a timestamp in Databricks SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a source table in databricks which has a field called `date`. I found that the `date` is like a timestamp. For example, it's data is `date = 2021-07-09 00:07` , `date = 2021-12-21 09:19`.

The above date is not a full timestamp, so I casted it as a string and I got the following results

```
cast(date as string) = 2021-07-09 00:07:09.529, 2021-12-21 09:19:21.019
```

I would like to know why casting it to a string is giving the milli seconds and is there any to_timestamp like function to cast the date instead of casting as string.

Can the date casted as string be compared with other dates casted as string?

Comment: when I was executing same command , I did't face this issue . can you please share the screenshot as I have i tried in both databricks notebook through %sql magical command and databricks SQL (sql endpoints ) . Both side are not populating with milli sec when cast from date to string.

Answer (score 0):

if the `date` field has timestamp, then what you see is just visual representation that may omit some non-essential details - internally it's stored in more compact representation, like, `long` representing number of milliseconds. But when you do cast to string, then this compact representation is used & you get all details.

To cast `timestamp` type to `date` type, just do `cast(date as date)`.  If you want to convert string into date or timestamp, just use [to_date](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/to_date.html) or [to_timestamp](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/to_timestamp.html) functions that allow to specify a format string that will be used for parsing of string components. And if you want to convert date or timestamp field into string and control the format of the string, then you need to look onto [date_format](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/date_format.html) function.

P.S. You can always refer to the [SQL Reference](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/index.html) that is the part of official Databricks documentation

Comment: If I used to_timestamp, the result I got was ```2021-07-09 00:09``` where as cast as string outputted ```2021-07-09 00:09:09.571```